# Trouble with email setup for Wikimedia site

Tags: google-cloud-platform, debian, mediawiki, mailgun, bitnami

I'm using Google Cloud Engine, Bitnami, and Mailgun to set up a Mediawiki site (v1.33.1-1 on Debian 9). I'm very new to every one of things.

My Mailgun is properly set up and verified, and I'm following the documentation provided here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-mailgun

When I run:

```
echo 'Test passed.' | mail -s 'Test-Email' EMAIL@EXAMPLE.COM
```

And then:

```
tail -n 5 /var/log/syslog
```

These are my results:

```
root@bitnami-mediawiki-860c:~# tail -n 5 /var/log/syslog
Nov 15 03:58:39 bitnami-mediawiki-860c postfix/qmgr[13119]: 8E84FA13DA: from=<>, size=2918, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 15 03:58:39 bitnami-mediawiki-860c postfix/bounce[13144]: 7A557A13D9: sender non-delivery notification: 8E84FA13DA
Nov 15 03:58:39 bitnami-mediawiki-860c postfix/qmgr[13119]: 7A557A13D9: removed
Nov 15 03:58:39 bitnami-mediawiki-860c postfix/smtp[13142]: 8E84FA13DA: to=<root@bitnami-mediawiki-860c>, relay=none, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=
5.4.4, status=bounced (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=bitnami-mediawiki-860c type=AAAA: Host not found)
Nov 15 03:58:39 bitnami-mediawiki-860c postfix/qmgr[13119]: 8E84FA13DA: removed
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this? Be specific if you can, as I'm beginning from nearly zero prior knowledge.

Comment: Google Cloud Platform does not allow SMTP traffic through default ports 25, 465 or 587. You will need to use an alternative service like sendgrid that allows you send SMTP without using the default ports. You can learn more about this in [our documentation](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/how-to/troubleshoot-smtp-issues/)

Comment: Did you configure it to use port 2525 instead of 25?

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud by default has always blocked the [port 25](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/), however, you can use different ports, i.e. 587 and 465.

Those ports should work to send mails from an VM instance, which could be the root cause for this to not being working as expected. It should work as mentioned on the comments with the port 2525.